# VS2010 LNK1181: cannot open input file 'Release\.NETFramework,Version'

Tags: visual-studio-2010, linker

I've been through the similar questions and their answers don't seem to apply.
Keep getting this error. Works ok with VS6.0
Checked all the settings and can't see NETFramework,Version or simialr anywhere in the project properties. Checked linker settings and can't see the input file NETFramework or Version anywhere.

cheers

Comment: How have you run this with the VS2010 linker? Have you upgraded the original solution/project? Anymore information on the source project would be helpful.

Comment: Hmm, your project conversion did not go well.  No so surprising considering the number of major VS releases you skipped.  You'd better create a new project from scratch.